# Quickest Schengen visa in Atlanta

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I have an Indian passport, with F-1 visa living in US. I am travelling to India via Europe (exact point of change of flight isn't fixed, but it is either Amsterdam, Paris or the Frankfurt.) I wish to visit a friend in Paris for 4-5 days while coming back. (And also, we might travel to Netherlands or Spain in this period)

I am wondering, which consulate to apply for tourist Schengen visa in Atlanta, my trip starts on 23rd of May, so I have little more than 3 weeks time. While, it may be considered safe time frame, I wish to expedite the visa approval so that I can book the tickets.

More info:
In the past, I have been issued Schengen visa twice: One a student visa from Chennai consulate in India; another, a Business visa issued from Swiss consulate in Atlanta. (Business visa from swiss consulate in Atlanta was issued in just one day, despite they said it might take a week.)

Comment: Have you tried applying for a visa at French consulate where you should apply.

Comment: Everything you need to know: http://www.consulfrance-atlanta.org/spip.php?article2738

Comment: Since France is your main destination, you are required to apply to the French consulate.  If you think you can get a visa more quickly at a different consulate, you have to change your itinerary so that either (1) that country is your main destination, or (2) your trip has no clear main destination and that country is the point of entry to the Schengen area.